# Lumen Model Static Boot Method Not Working?

Tags: php, lumen-5.4

I am using lumen 5.6 and implementing global scopes for query builder and using the boot method to call the scope class. Can someone have an idea why `protected static function boot()` not working in `lumen 5.6` Below is my code?

```
<?php

use App\Scopes\FilterSites;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class AccountTag extends Model {

var $useTable = 'tags_tbl';
var $primaryKey = 'tag_id';

protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new FilterSites);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncomment the line where `$app->withEloquent();` is written in `bootstrap/app.php`. The **withEloquent()** method registers the **DatabaseServiceProvider** and bootstrap **Eloquent ORM**.

You can test that your global filter is applied by registering a route that returns the sql statement for selecting all items in the model.

In `routes/web.php`,

```
$router->get('/account-tags', function () {
    return App\AccountTag::toSql();
});
```

When you browse the endpoint, the returned query should have a where clause matching `FilterSites`

Comment: I register that in `/bootstrap/app.php` can you please tell me how I can use this in my model. And after doing that will my boot method will work or not?

Comment: Please see updated answer. You only need to uncomment the `$app->withEloquent()` line in `/bootstrap/app.php` and you should be good to go with the globalScope registered in the `AccountTag` model.